# How to create a python program that will display the sum of every number plus 1 from the entered number until the count reaches the entered number

Tags: python-3.x

this is what i have so far but i need the program to end at 10. it goes on forever right now

```
number = int(input("enter: "))  
count = number

while count <= count:  
    print(count)  
    count = count + 1  
print("Done")
```

Comment: `count <= count` will always be true even if count keeps incrementing. Can you please clarify the question?

Comment: so when the user enters a 6 the program will count 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12

Comment: also printing out 6 number. if a 3 was entered it will be 4,5,6

Comment: If a solution suit your need you should accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this look like an assignment.. If it is you should try harder( a hint may be a for loop is more suited here)

#### spoiler / solution

```
number = int(input("enter: "))  
count = number

for indice in range(1, number + 1 , 1):
    print(number + indice)

print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

`count <= count` will always be true.

You want `count <= number`

You also probably want to start the count at 0, and your code isn't doing any summing right now. You will need a third variable to keep track of the sum.